# Retrieve differents Qmap in a single variable

Tags: c++, qt, casting, qlist, qmap

I am working on a game in Qt.
My characters/objects are stored in my model Class (I try to follow the MVC model).

I created a QMap containing for each of the object :

```
QMap<int, Safe*> *safes;
QMap<int, Mushroom*> *mushroom;
QMap<int, Floor*> *floors;
```

But then I would like to retrieve all theses QMap in my Controller and send it to the paintEvent() class of my View from the controller.
Is there a way to store the QMap in a QList like this :

```
QList<QMap<int, void*>>
```

And then cast it ? I am searching for a way to acces to theses QMap from a single object.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: unrelated, but why pointers to qmap?

Comment: because I modify them in my controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a struct to bundle them up inside one object:

```
struct Maps
{
    QMap<int, Safe*> *safes;
    QMap<int, Mushroom*> *mushroom;
    QMap<int, Floor*> *floors;
};
```

Although it's valid to have a pointer to QMap, if you don't need to hold a pointer to it then I would advise against it.

```
struct Maps
{
    QMap<int, Safe*> safes;
    QMap<int, Mushroom*> mushroom;
    QMap<int, Floor*> floors;
};
```

That way you don't have to worry about heap allocations/deallocations.

If you have a compiler that supports C++11 then you can use [std::tuple](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/) to group items together.

```
std::tuple<QMap, QMap, QMap> maps (safes, mushroom, floors);
```

Comment: Perhaps using a class would be better. I assume that if he wants to group them somehow he will want to apply operations. Having a class would probably be better for this reason no? +1 for the pointer to QMap

Comment: By the way, there's something called `std::tuple` if you want to be lightweight and convenient :)

Comment: @LBesancon As you know in C++ the only difference between a struct and a class is their default access specifiers and the way they are inherited. So you could have methods in your struct if you wanted to. I do however tend to use structs when I need to group some data together without any methods but it's completely down to you.

Comment: @yzn-pku You're absolutely right. I will update my answer.

Comment: @MohamadElghawi sure you can have methods in your struct. It is more a matter of what you're used to do. Basically I tend to create classes whenever the need arises but you're right. Did not downvote your answer anyway for that ;)

Answer (score 1):

First, yes you can use a `QList` for this purpose, however I would suggest to create an interface class first and use this in your `QMap`.

```
struct GameObjectInterface {
};

class Safe : public GameObjectInterface {};
class Mushroom : public GameObjectInterface {};
class Floor : public GameObjectInterface {};

QMap<int, GameObjectInterface*> _GameObjects;

// Is game object with ID `n` a `Safe`?

Safe* s = dynamic_cast<Safe*>(_GameObjects[n]);
if (s != nullptr) {
    // Yes it is a safe
}
```

Another possibility:

```
QList<QMap<int, GameObjectInterface*>> _GameObjects;
```

And if you want you can capsule everything into one struct as hinted by other responders.

```
struct MyGameObject {
    QMap<int, Safe*> Safes;
    QMap<int, Mushrooms*> Mushrooms;
    QMap<int, Floor*> Floors;
};

QList<MyGameObject> _GameObjects;
```

If each are related (same key for all objects) it could be simplified like:

```
struct MyGameObject {
    Safe* _Safe;
    Mushrooms* _Mushroom;
    Floor* _Floor;
};
QMap<int, MyGameObject*> _GameObjects;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could keep pointer to base class for all your specific objects:

```
QMap<int, MyBaseClass*> allObjects;
```